# PasswordAuthentication no, but I can still login by password

Tags: ssh, authentication

Why can I still ssh into my Ubuntu machine using a password? This is the  `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file of my Ubuntu 20.04 on ovh hosting (showing only non-commented lines for brevity):

```
Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf
Port xxx
PermitRootLogin no
AllowUsers      user1 user2
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

The permissions of the relevant files seem to be OK:

```
$ stat -c %a /home/user1/.ssh/
700

$ stat -c %a /home/user1/.ssh/authorized_keys`
600
```

I have run `sudo service ssh restart` and `sudo service sshd restart`.

Why am I still able to log into my Ubuntu machine by password over ssh? I can login by user and password over ssh (PuTTY), it only asks for password. Both user1 and user2 have their key in .ssh home folder. 
What is missing?

I checked the include file:

```
-rw------- 1 root root   27 Dec  1 12:52 50-cloud-init.conf
...:/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d$ sudo cat 50-cloud-init.conf
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

so I guess that is the cause? 
However, wouldn’t my config overwrite this setting?
since it is included above (line wise)?

Comment: Did you run `sudo service sshd restart` or did you only restart `ssh`? These are setting for the sshd service (the ssh server) not the ssh service (ssh client).

Comment: oh boy. i only run ssh not sshd. man! thanks

Comment: Did that solve it?

Comment: i restarted sshd, but still can login by password......

Comment: OK, then please [edit] your question and add this. Also tell us what this `sshd` config file is, where did you find it (we need to be sure you are editing the right file).

Comment: And if you edit sshd_config with `UsePAM No` (and restart sshd) ?  Also, are there any files included via the `Include` line at the top of the file, or is that directory empty of relevant files?

Comment: @terdon is there really a separate ssh client service? AFAIK, the server service is really named `ssh`, and `sshd` is just an alias (`/etc/systemd/system/sshd.service -> /lib/systemd/system/ssh.service`) specified via the ssh.service file's `[Install]` section

Comment: @steeldriver you know more about this than I do. All I know is that I have been able to have only `ssh` running on an Ubuntu machine and that would let me ssh from it to other machines, but I needed `sshd` to be able to ssh from other machines into the Ubuntu one. Or so I seem to recall, anyway. It's been a while, I may well be wrong.

Comment: @terdon right - but the ssh client (that allows you to connect from your box) is just an ordinary userland application rather than a service, I think?

Comment: @steeldriver see the first sentence of my previous comment ;) We have reached the end of my, very limited, knowledge on this. I am sure you're right.

Comment: @terdon well tbh I had to check the docs to understand how it works ;) I hadn't come across the systemd alias mechanism before

Comment: see my edit. also i did not want to touch PAM config, as I do not know what it does

Comment: @koko, from `man sshd_config`: "For eack keyword, the first obtained value will be used."

Comment: @koko if you found a solution, please post it below _as an answer_ instead of adding it to your question.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Ubuntu/Debian distributions have the non-standard entry `Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf` at the beginning of the distribution `sshd_config`.  The purpose of this is to allow users to customize their sshd configuration without modifying the core `sshd_config` file, which can minimize conflicts or unexpected configuration changes on `apt update` of OpenSSH.

Because the *first* encountered configuration line is the one applied, any password commands in a custom configuration file in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf` will pre-empt the `PasswordAuthentication no` line in the primary configuration.  Ensure that all configuration is as you expect.

As noted by @dexter, you can output the effective configuration with `sudo sshd -T`, which may highlight when one configuration file overrides another.

Answer (score 10):

Login by password could be performed not only with `PasswordAuthentication`. Actually, it is the "dedicated simple" method of authentication, and there is a generic method which, amongst others, can do password authentication - `KbdInteractiveAuthentication`, formerly known as ChallengeResponseAuhentication. It is a generic chat-like (that's what challenge response stands for) authentication, which can be made dual factor, use one-time passwords and so on, by asking additional or customized questions, while the former only allows exactly what it names — authentication by system password.

`UsePAM` controls somewhat how `KbdInteractiveAuthentication` (a.k.a. `ChallengeResponseAuthentication`) could replace/duplicate the `PasswordAuthentication`. PAM could provide challenge-response chat to sshd, and PAM *usually* is configured with `pam_unix.so` which performs traditional password authentication, so `UsePAM` + `KbdInteractiveAuthentication` effectively provides password authentication for SSH. (Thanks @TooTea for noticing this.)

See the most upvoted answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/161609/can-someone-explain-the-passwordauthentication-in-the-etc-ssh-sshd-config-fil) (it's a shame it isn't the accepted answer, because it is clearly better), and also see `man sshd_config`, of course.

Comment: I also wondered whether "UsePAM yes" could allow passwords. No PAM specialist...

Comment: @U.Windl Only in combination with ChallengeResponse/KbdInteractive. That's exactly what it does, provide a mechanism for PAM modules to interactively chat with the client, so it's typically PAM printing the exact same "Password:" prompt as on a local TTY, etc. If this mechanism is disabled, PAM modules have no way to interact with the user, so they can only use the password supplied to them by SSH (from the builtin PasswordAuthentication prompt, which runs before PAM is invoked).

Comment: @TooTea thank you for noticing this, I put that into the answer.

Answer (score 4):

The include file had `PasswordAuthentication yes` which was used, thanks to `man sshd_config`: *"For each keyword, the first obtained value will be used."*

Now if I try to login via SSH, I *"No supported authentication methods available (public key)"*.

Only SSH key works.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the order matters when using `match` sections.

This one will work:

```
Match User user-special
    PasswordAuthentication yes

Match User user-ftp
    AuthorizedKeysFile /home/user-ftp/.ssh/authorized_keys
    ChrootDirectory /DATA/s2survey
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no

Match all
    PasswordAuthentication no
    KbdInteractiveAuthentication no
    ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
```

This order, however will not work as expected. Either the `PasswordAuthentication` is ignored (was not able to find out why) or it will not be changed in the more specific `match` sections.

```
PasswordAuthentication no
KbdInteractiveAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

Match User user-special
    PasswordAuthentication yes

Match User user-ftp
    AuthorizedKeysFile /home/user-ftp/.ssh/authorized_keys
    ChrootDirectory /DATA/s2survey
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no

Match all
```